# Connecting to remote server using java and ssh key

Tags: java, ssh

Does anyone have any code for connecting to a remote server using java and an ssh key.
We dont have a password for this server, we just use our username and our ssh keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is a pure java SSH implementation that supports SSH key auth.

Comment: FYI, refer to its sample program, [http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html)

Answer (score 1):

[SSHJ](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj) have very easy & clean API for uploading files and for executing commands on remote systems.